# Using toggleClass to toggle between image heights, 250px - 450px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am building a website which is really image heavy, a portfolio site.

I have a masonry type gallery with each image set to 250px height by default. I wish to create a hyperlink/button which will let the user decide if they want to view the images at normal size (250px) or at a larger size (450px).

The images are loaded inside a div called `#imageGallery`, I would like to understand the best way to have a button that once clicked, will add/toggle/remove a class that will resize all the images in the div to 450px.

Comment: See `classList.toggle`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList (or, if you use jQuery, `toggleClass`: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: If you're using jQuery [why not read the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a basic usage of the `toggleClass` jQuery function.

```js
$('#toggleBtn').click(function(){
  $('.item').toggleClass( "expand" );  
});
```

```css
.item{
  height:250px;
}
.expand{
  height:450px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggleBtn">toggle</button>
<div id="imageGallery">
  <img class="item" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAbcF7stPcRmmZxkwuyoPewIEvnYQZvvTJ_f79-ZJ0TFsCn5NJUQ" />
  <img class="item" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAbcF7stPcRmmZxkwuyoPewIEvnYQZvvTJ_f79-ZJ0TFsCn5NJUQ" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked a treat, and it has already been plugged in and is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the thumbnails will have the same class name. When the button is toggled, you can select all the thumbnails with jquery and [toggle a class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for those elements.

```
function buttonClick(e) {
  var thumbnails = $('.thumbnail');
  thumbnails.toggleClass('.large-image');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not put a class on each element, I would put the class on the parent and use CSS rule based off that class to update the heights.

```
.grid-item { height: 250px; }
.expanded .grid-item { height: 450px; }
```

and than with the toggling of the class

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("#imageGallery).toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

or Vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("imageGallery").classList.toggle("expanded"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look ma - no JavaScript (admittedly, not the most beautiful HTML either ... but it works).

```css
ul.gallery {
    list-style-tye: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul.gallery img {
    height: 100px;
}

input#sizing:checked ~ ul img {
    height: 200px
}

input#sizing {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="sizing"><label for="sizing">Display in Large</label>
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/51/32/15/513215ec15a8596180e19a7a18ddcea0.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```